# How can I successfully fit data to a Morse potential with scipy.optimize.curve_fit?

Tags: scipy, curve-fitting

I have a list of distances vs energies and I'm trying to fit it to a Morse potential using scipy.optimize.curve_fit. The data is:

distances: [0.7,  0.78, 0.86, 0.94, 1.02, 1.1,  1.18, 1.26]

energies: [-1428.03995379, -1428.13375727, -1428.18294153, -1428.20472839,
-1428.20977469, -1428.2047732,  -1428.19393863, -1428.17996123]

and the Morse potential is:

```py
def morsePotential(r, D, alpha, r0):
    return D * (1 - np.exp(-alpha * (r - r0)))**2
```

When I do

```py
param, cv = curve_fit(morsePotential, distances, energies, np.array([0.005, 10, 1.0]))
D, alpha, r0 = param
```

scipy says it cannot estimate the covariance and the fit produces completely ridiculous output, for example D << 0, which makes no sense for this potential, where D is the depth of the energy well. I am also having trouble fitting these data to a harmonic potential, which is even more worrying. What can I do to nudge curve_fit in the right direction? Right now it is either returning nonsense values or failing completely.

Comment: Check your modeling assumptions.  The values in `energies` are all negative values near -1428, but the function defined as `morsePotential` can never be negative, so something is fundamentally wrong with your approach.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by Warren Weckesser the function  y(r) = D * (1 - np.exp(-alpha * (r - r0)))**2 is not convenient to correctly fit it to the given data.

Of course the best way is to find a better model from physical considerations. On the other hand, the function proposed below comes only from mathematical adjustment. This is a second best solution.

[image]